# Spring Boot pass async data to view

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a little problem with my Spring Boot application.
I try to make async API call using WebClient, but how can i pass data from async response to html view?

Here is my Controller code:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HomeController {

private final WebClient.Builder webBuilder;

@GetMapping("/")
public String getHomepage() {
    return "homepage";
}

@GetMapping("/api")
public String getApiResponse() {
    webBuilder.build()
            .get()
            .uri("https://api.github.com/users/microsoft/repos")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .subscribe(response -> {
                // Async Response pass data to view
            });
    return "apitest";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to do somethink like this:

```
Map<String, Object> models = new HashMap<>();
    Mono<List<GithubRepo>> listMono = webBuilder.build()
            .get()
            .uri("https://api.github.com/users/microsoft/repos")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {});
    CompletableFuture<List<GithubRepo>> listCompletableFuture = listMono.toFuture();
    List<GithubRepo> repos = listCompletableFuture.join();
    models.put("json", repos);
    return new ModelAndView("apitest", models);
```

It is correct for web application?

I made 2 tests. One using block() function and one using this method, and this method is faster than block(), but i don't know it's correct method.

EDIT: Using method above, my TTFB after first start is 1 second, but after refresh it's between 40ms and 100ms.

Maybe is better way to do that?

Comment: As this is your tried approach and asking the suggestion, you can append the details in as part of question itself

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I want to pass data from async webclient task to HTML view, but i don't know how to do that the best